# Xcode5 xcodebuild failed when the precompile header includes Pods-environment.h and execute pod install before xcodebuild

Tags: cocoapods, xcode5

Simplified version of build script is:

```
# change Podfild here 
pod install
xcodebuild
```

It works with Xcode 4.6, but with Xcode5-DP5 it failed.

```
fatal error: file '/path/to/myproject/Pods/Pods-environment.h' has been modified
  since the precompiled header
  '/Users/hiroshi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gfmuvpipjscewkdnqacgumhfarrd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Prefix-dwjpvcnrlaydzmegejmcvrtcfkpf/MyProject-Prefix.pch.pch'
  was built
```

Comment: The same is happening in one of my projects. I think it happens only if you have pods pointing directly to a git repo head (instead to normal cocoapod version endpoints). It's annoying having to clean the entire project. Does anyone know how to configure the project to automatically delete the precompiled header when Cocoapods are updated?

Comment: Yeah, I have pod lines with :git and :path in my Podfile. I guess you got a point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It succeeded after changed `buildactions` like this.

```
# change Podfild here 
pod install
xcodebuild clean build
```

I guess Xcode5 won't re-precompile the precompile header only the default `build` buildaciton, need to do `clean` first.